# How do I send these Jquery Variables off to Mysql via php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I made a simple (yet unconventional) form which stores each answer as a variable (I did it this way because some questions won't be answered because some questions showing up depend on what you answered on the previous question).

I would like to send that off to a php file which will search if there's a match in a Mysql database, and return it in an xml format.

Here are the variables:

- **Answer1:** If filled, must equal to what is in mysql
- **Checkbox1/2/3/3:** Will retrieve data if one or more of these is checked. For example, if 'coffee' and 'juice' is checked, rows that have either coffee or juice set to true will be returned.
- **Dropdown1/2:** Two from/to variables that specify a range

Here is my code :)
http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/S6smg/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="que1">Question One:
    <input id="inp1" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Next Question" id="but1"></div>

<div id="que2" class="hiddendiv">Question Two:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="coffee">Coffee<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="tea">Tea<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="latte">Latte<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value="juice">Juice<br>
    <input type="button" value="Next Question" id="but2"></div>

<div id="que3" class="hiddendiv">Question Three:
    From:
    <select id="dropdown1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    To:
    <select id="dropdown2">
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Finish" id="but3"></div>

<br><br><br>
<b>Variables</b><br>
Answer1:<div id="answer1"></div>
Checkbox1:<div id="answer2a"></div>
Checkbox2:<div id="answer2b"></div>
Checkbox3:<div id="answer2c"></div>
Checkbox4:<div id="answer2d"></div>
Dropdown1:<div id="answer3a"></div>
Dropdown2:<div id="answer3b"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    var question1 = '';
    var question2a = '';
    var question2b = '';
    var question2c = '';
    var question2d = '';
    var question3a = '';
    var question3b = '';
    switch (this.id) {
    case 'but1':
        question1 = $("#inp1").val();
        $("#answer1").html(question1);
        $('#que1').addClass('hiddendiv');
        $('#que2').removeClass('hiddendiv');
    break;
    case 'but2':
        if($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')){
        question2a = '1';
        }
        if($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')){
        question2b = '1';
        }
        if($('#checkbox3').is(':checked')){
        question2c = '1';
        }
        if($('#checkbox4').is(':checked')){
        question2d = '1';
        }
        $("#answer2a").html(question2a);
        $("#answer2b").html(question2b);
        $("#answer2c").html(question2c);
        $("#answer2d").html(question2d);
        $('#que2').addClass('hiddendiv');
        $('#que3').removeClass('hiddendiv');
    break;
    case 'but3':
        question3a = $("#dropdown1").val();
        question3b = $("#dropdown2").val();
        $('#que3').addClass('hiddendiv');
        $("#answer3a").html(question3a);
        $("#answer3b").html(question3b);
    break;
}
});
```

Thank you very much everyone :)))!

Here's what the php file looks like now for my older html form:

```
<?php
require("db_access.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

$name=$_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$type=$_POST['type'];


// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}




// Select all the rows in the markers table
$inputs = array('name', 'address', 'type');
$where  = array();

foreach($inputs as $input)
{
    if(!empty($_POST[$input])) {
        $where[] = "{$input} = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$input]) . "'";
    }
}

if ($where) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM markers WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
} else {
    user_error("No rows returned by:<br />\n$query"); 
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result == false) {
   die(mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query");
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   user_error("No rows returned by:<br />\n$query");
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . parseToXML($row['type']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an HTTP request to the PHP page, and handle the form data on the server side. Depending on the form type, it will be in either `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

If you want to do it using AJAX, you can use a [form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) or do it manually by collecting the data and submitting it with `$.get`.

1. Assign a `name` value to each form element.
2. Use the `name` to pull the form data from the, for example, if the field is named `foo` and you're requesting data with POST, you would use `$_POST['foo']`
   .

Comment: Hi Nick, I have posted a php source that I use now for a simple 3 question form. However, I'm not sure how to port these variables off into that file

Comment: Ahh, so I don't even need to use variables then ? However I just realized that I have a question where four buttons decide what the next question will be - which is why I decided to use variables. Can I somehow transfer one of the button clicks to a name value?

Comment: No offense, but you should consider getting a book on PHP/JavaScript. This is really basic stuff. You can bind a click event to a function using `$.bind` with jQuery.

Comment: Sorry if the question sounded too simple Nick, you're right I am really new to this - I'm currently looking stuff up on Amazon so hopefully I will get better :)